# reshape numpy 2d array into pandas 1d

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array as follow

```
a.shape =  (100, 500)
```

would like to tranform into pandas dataframe as follow

```
   df.shape =  (100 * 500, 1)
   df[500*i+j,0]  = a[i, j]
```

without loop...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I'm missing something, but isn't it a simple flattening?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a.flatten())
```

If I misunderstood what you mean by `i` and `j`, a transpose should do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a.T.flatten())
```